# Timezone inaccuracy

Tags: linux, centos, command-line-interface, timezone

we've been having an issue getting time synced across our Litespeed web cluster, that being that the system time (we're using CentOS) appears to be thinking that the current time for EST  (Being the "America/New_York") time zone is 3 hours ahead of current time.

In Florida right now the time is 10:53PM
The server reports this:
TZ='America/New_York' will be used.
Local time is now:      Tue Jun  4 01:51:43 EDT 2013.
Universal Time is now:  Tue Jun  4 05:51:43 UTC 2013.

What would cause something like this? The same is applying in our PHP.ini configuration for the cluster.

This is the response from a perfectly fine web-server which is configured exactly the same:
TZ='America/New_York' will be used.
Local time is now:      Mon Jun  3 22:53:15 EDT 2013.

--Update 1--
ntp peers on a WORKING server:

```
krillin.ecansol 184.164.149.162  2 u   52   64    1   35.631  110337. 7937.50
 ntp.sunflower.c 184.164.149.162 16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000 15937.5
 triangle.kansas 184.164.149.162  2 u   50   64    1   55.125  110331. 7937.50
```

ntp peers on a BROKEN server:

```
 fairy.mattnordh 164.244.221.197  2 u   59   64    7   49.397  -108052   1.171
 ec2-50-16-231-1 209.51.161.238   2 u   60   64    7   59.565  -108052   0.016
 colossus915.ser 200.23.51.102    2 u   59   64    7   46.693  -108052   0.051
```

Comment: Why are any of your servers anything but UTC?

Comment: That really doesn't answer the question, but the reason is that our company operates out of Florida and our payroll system is dependent upon times syncing up with Floridian time (EST) and thus for this special case we need the cluster to serve pages based on EST.

Comment: We'll try to ignore just how screwed up that line of thinking is for a moment and focus on time synchronization. How are your `ntpd` configured on each server? Are they synchronizing against the NTP.org Pool? Do they peer with each other?

Comment: I'm not the most experienced when it comes to ntp and the configuration of ntpd, but I have updated the question to contain the peers that our servers are using for both a working and broken server. Let me know what other information you need.

Comment: Er, that's not the configuration data... try `/etc/ntp.conf`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mg2yLjSG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you've specifically configured your OS to expect otherwise, your server's system clock **must** reflect UTC, not local timezone. Timezone offsets are applied after-the-fact, as multiple timezones can be used at the same time on a single server. Your timezone file tells the server what time to return given the assumption that the system clock is set to UTC.

NTPd will refuse to synchronize if the system clock is too far off the target clock. You have to manually set it to something within a minute or so of the target time (UTC); either that or use `ntpdate` to fetch the time from an NTP server and immediately set the clock accordingly. *Then* you can run ntpd to fine-tune your clock to get the millisecond precision you need.

After a warm-up time, `ntpq -pn` should show one remote server marked with a `*` on the left to indicate that it has been been declared the primary synchronization peer, with others hopefully marked with a `+` to indicate that they are qualified back-up candidates for peering.

If not, then your clock is not being synchronized.

Note that in the list of peers, the offset should be less than 1ms [absolute value] in normal running condition, perhaps a few hundred ms as the clock gets fine-tuned. Your list shows an offset so far out of range that synchronization using clock slewing is impossible. Instead, you'll need to "jump" your clock to the correct time, something ntpd will by policy never do on its own. That's what the `ntpdate` tool is for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `ntpd` with the `-g` option?  It should be specified in `/etc/sysconfig/ntpd`.  Without `-g`, `ntpd` will refuse to set the clock if it is off by more than 1000 seconds.